# How to read qr code using laptop camera and Zxing in JavaSE/EE?

Tags: java, qr-code, java-ee-7

I need to read a qr code using Java using the notebook camera. I found examples on how to do it in Android but nothing in desktop. Is Zxing the best library to do it? Anyone know a good tutorial about it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

to grab an image from a cam you can use JMF ( Java Media Framework) ( bit outdated ) 
or this project https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

Zxing is a good choice to read the barcode from the image

Complete example can be found herer https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-qrcode

Not sure if about your java-ee-7 tag. Should the app running on a application server ?